# JQuery unbind (scroll) function does not work

Tags: jquery

According to JQuery documentation this have to work, but it doesn't.

The scrollHandler() function is called when the popup is shown and have to be destroyed if closed, however the unbind doesn't seem to work. If I do a full $(window).unbind('scroll') it does work, but it unbinds other elements attached to the scroll event as well.

Code is at: http://codepen.io/nicotinell/pen/dogJGJ the whole scroll event fiasco happens between line 23 and 44 just to save you a couple of seconds.

Demo (where cookies actually work) is at: http://codepen.io/nicotinell/full/dogJGJ/

```
/* Crate Slug */
    function convertToSlug(text) {
        return text
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'')
        .replace(/ +/g,'-');
    }

    /**/
        function handleEyeCatcher(slug){
            console.log($.cookie());
            console.log(slug);
            /* If not set, create default cookie */
            if(!$.cookie(slug)) {
                $.cookie(slug, 'true', { expires: 7 });
                $('#eye-catch').addClass('visible');
            }

            /* Status */
            var status = $.cookie(slug);
            console.log(status);

            /* Scroll Function */
            function scrollHandler () {
                var height = $(window).height();
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > height) {
                    $('#eye-catch').removeClass('invisible');
                    $('#eye-catch').addClass('visible');
                } else {
                    $('#eye-catch').removeClass('visible');
                    $('#eye-catch').addClass('invisible');
                }
            }
            /* Hide/show element depending on cookie */
            if(status == 'true'){
                console.log('it is opened');
                $(window).bind('scroll', scrollHandler);
            } else {
                $(window).unbind('scroll', scrollHandler);
                console.log('it is closed');
                $('#eye-catch').removeClass('visible');
                $('#eye-catch').addClass('invisible');
            }
        }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* Get raw slug */
            var rawSlug= $('#eye-catch .title').text();
        /* Convert to cookie name friendly slug */
            var slug = convertToSlug(rawSlug);

        handleEyeCatcher(slug);

        /* Hide and update cookie on click */
        $('#eye-catch .close').on('click', function(){
            $.cookie(slug, 'false', { expires: 7 });
            handleEyeCatcher(slug);
        });

        /* Revert action */
        $('#revert').on('click', function(){
            $.cookie(slug, 'true', { expires: 7 });
            handleEyeCatcher(slug);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Should be using `.on()` and `.off()` these days, not `.bind()` and `.unbind()`.

Comment: Thought: `function scrollHandler() {...}` is defined anew every time `handleEyeCatcher()` is called. Therefore, `.unbind('scroll', scrollHandler)` is guaranteed only to see the instance of that function determined by the rules of closure. Try moving `scrollHandler()` outside `handleEyeCatcher()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! I've read about bind/unbind and on/off - turns out it's pretty much the same and works both ways. The real trick was in fact moving the scrollHandler() function outside handleEyeCatcher(). If you add your comments as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, `function scrollHandler() {...}` is defined anew every time `handleEyeCatcher()` is called.

Therefore, `.unbind('scroll', scrollHandler)` is guaranteed only to see the instance of that function determined by the rules of closure.

Try moving `scrollHandler()` outside `handleEyeCatcher()`, then `unbind('scroll', scrollHandler)` will be guaranteed to see the one-and-only `scrollHandler`.